# wordpressでのフリーワード検索とtaxonomyとカスタムフィールドのAND検索は可能なのか

Tags: wordpress

```
    $venue_type = $_GET['vt'];
    $guest_count = $_GET['gc'];
    $area = $_GET['area'];
    $keyword = $_GET['s'];

    $the_query = new WP_Query();

    if($keyword){ $taxquerysp[] = array( 'taxonomy'=>'category', 'terms'=> $keyword);}
    if($keyword){ $taxquerysp[] = array( 'taxonomy'=>'post_tag', 'terms'=> $keyword);}
    $taxquerysp['relation'] = 'OR';

    if($venue_type){ $metaquerysp[] = array( 'key'=>'venue_type', 'value'=> $venue_type );}
    if($guest_count){ $metaquerysp[] = array( 'key'=>'guest_count', 'value'=> $guest_count );}
    $metaquerysp['relation'] = 'AND';

    if($metaquerysp || $area || $keyword){
      $query1 = array(
        'post_type' => 'wedding_reports',
        'tax_query' => $taxquerysp,
        'meta_query' => $metaquerysp,
        's' => $keyword
      );
      $current_articl1 = new WP_Query($query1);
    }
```

上記のような検索を実現したいのですが、wordpressでのフリーワード検索とtaxonomyとカスタムフィールドのAND検索は可能なのでしょうか？

よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 1):

AND検索は可能です。

関数:WP_Queryやget_postsは、パラメータ'tax_query'、'meta_query'、's'などが同時に指定されるとAND条件で記事データを抽出します。

wordpressがフォルダー”word”にインストールされ
カスタムフィールド　abcdef_abc に 'dog'が　
カテゴリに、a1 が　設定されている記事で
フリーワード検索で'ねこ'が存在するデータを絞り込むなら、以下のコード実行すると確認する事が出来ると思います。

```
require "word/wp-config.php";

$ptype ='post';

$taxonomyc =
    array(array(
        'taxonomy' => 'category',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => 'a1'
    ));

$metac =
    array(
        array(
            'key' => 'abcdef_abc',
            'value' => 'dog',
        )
    );

$current_articl1 = new WP_Query(array('numberposts'=> 5000, 'order'=> 'DESC', 'orderby' => 'post_date','post_type' => $ptype,'tax_query' => $taxonomyc,'meta_query' => $metac,'s'=>'ねこ'));
$pt = get_posts(array('numberposts'=> 5000, 'order'=> 'DESC', 'orderby' => 'post_date','post_type' => $ptype,'tax_query' => $taxonomyc,'meta_query' => $metac,'s'=>'ねこ'));
print_r($pt);
```

WP_Query関数がパラメータを展開したSQLは以下の通りです。（$current_articl1−＞requestに入っています。）

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts  LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id) INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id ) WHERE 1=1  AND (
  wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (2)
) AND (((wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%ねこ%') OR (wp_posts.post_excerpt LIKE '%ねこ%') OR (wp_posts.post_content LIKE '%ねこ%')))  AND (wp_posts.post_password = '')  AND (
  ( wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'abcdef_abc' AND wp_postmeta.meta_value = 'dog' )
) AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish') GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 10
```